# Error 'Cannot recognize current file path' occurred when using syncfusion

Tags: c#, syncfusion

When trying to open an existing docx file by using suncfusion ,

> WordDocument document = new WordDocument(*filename.docx*);

"Cannot recognize current file path" error occurred.
Stack Trace: at Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS.WordDocument.WordDocumentType(String fileName, String password)

But I don't want a password to open this document.

Answer (score 0):

You should give full path instead of providing the file name alone. Please refer below code:

```
WordDocument document = new WordDocument(@"D:\XXX\FileName.docx");
```

Also ensure that the file exists in corresponding path.

Comment: Also you need to run your Visual Studio as administrator if you didn't. I've solved my problem with this trick. (running exe of your program as administrator is enough too.)